# fastboot: usage: no command

Tags: rooting, fastboot, android-sdk

Basic information: Windows - Android SDK - fastboot.exe

As the title says.. fastboot won't work in my cmd and fails with the output: `fastboot: usage: no command`. The android-sdk is located in the root directory (`C:\`). I also add the pathvariables in the system environment. I don’t try it with an android device, I only test if the command responds, but yeah it did not...! So I actually do everything like it's described in the tutorials, but can't find my mistake.
Did anyone have this problem or does know a solution?

Comment: Cross posting is discouraged (you have done it on two other sites)

Comment: @beeshyams Yeah I will delete one! I find this part of stock exchange one hour ago! But you don’t have a solution for my problem? ^^

Comment: What command did you actually issue? It's important that we can recreate your problem before we can diagnose it.

Comment: I only use the command “fastboot” so actually the possibilities of this application should be shown, if everything is configured in the right way! By the way “adb” works!

Comment: Are there any special drivers required to run this command in the basic way without a device?

Comment: @IrfanLatif ok lol, thank you, that work!  but why does only “fastboot” not work in the same way!?

Comment: @IrfanLatif Actually I use the latest version as well! That’s why I’m a bit confused! But whatever - it works 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `fastboot --help` instead. This is a kinda standard way to get usage help in Linux world. However sometimes writing only the command name also works as you expect.

[Reference:](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/eclair-release/fastboot/fastboot.c#548)

```
if (argc == 0) {
    usage();
    return 0;
}
```

[image]